# UIView line thickness is distorted after scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, border

I'm getting a weird problem while trying to draw a border of a view using another UIView with height = 1. 
I put those borders(UIViews with height = 1) in a scrollview, initially they're displayed just fine, but after scrolling some of the borders become thinner than they should. Here's a screenshot, you can see the border below "Password" field became thinner:

[image]

As far as I can notice, this problem only occurs on iPhone6 and 6Plus.

Do you have any idea about the cause of this problem? 
Thanks

**Edit** 
I just found out that this problem only occurs with my current project, when I copy the VC from my storyboard to another project, the problem just goes away.

Comment: simulator or real device?

Comment: Real devices, IP6 and IP6+. The screenshots are actually taken from real devices

Comment: I think the password textfiled is overlapping the border view, try setting the background of password field to clear color.

Comment: @Mr.UB that's not the case, I try removing both the fields and this problem still persists.

Comment: Have you set constraint to these borders?

Comment: check your launch screen image.

Comment: @Mr.UB the constraints for each view are: Trailling/leading to superview | height = 1 | Bottom to super view = 0.

Comment: @ajay_nasa How does it have anything to do with launch screen image?